# Click module Setuptools example didn't work out of the box

Tags: python, setuptools, python-click

[Click setuptools](http://click.pocoo.org/5/setuptools/#setuptools-integration) has two examples. I can get the first example to work, but not the second.

I understand there are still two files, but now `yourscript.py` is stored in a sub-directory `scripts`:

```
# yourscript.py
import click

@click.command()
def cli():
    """Example script."""
    click.echo('Hello World!')
```

Setup.py then supplys an argument `find_packages()` and `entry_points` uses a dot syntax to describe the location of `yourscript.py`

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='yourpackage',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'Click',
    ],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        yourscript=yourpackage.scripts.yourscript:cli
    ''',
)
```

I followed the example using virtualenv:

```
(clickenv) > pip install -e .  
Obtaining file:///home/...ClickSiteExample/yourscript
Requirement already satisfied: Click in /home/.../clickenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from yourpackage==0.1) (6.7)
Installing collected packages: yourpackage
  Running setup.py develop for yourpackage
Successfully installed yourpackage
```

Then here's the call to the script:

```
(clickenv) > yourscript        
    [...]
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yourpackage'
```

Something is missing in this error report, because the package is also shown as installed:

```
(clickenv) [130] > pip list
Package     Version Location                                                                            
----------- ------- --------------------------------------------------
click       6.7     
pip         10.0.0  
setuptools  39.0.1  
wheel       0.31.0  
yourpackage 0.1     /home/.../ClickSiteExample/yourpackage <<CORRECTED
```

This should be simple, so what's missing from the example?

---

UPDATE. I've recreated the directory minus the two unmentioned files, `main.py` and `utils.py`. I understand the `__init__.py` files are required but can be empty, and I've included those:

```
(clickenv) > tree 
.                                                                                
└── yourpackage  <<CORRECTED
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── scripts
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── yourscript.py
    ├── setup.py
    └── yourpackage.egg-info
        ├── dependency_links.txt
        ├── entry_points.txt
        ├── PKG-INFO
        ├── requires.txt
        ├── SOURCES.txt
        └── top_level.txt
```

Comment: The directory structure is incomplete. You don't have subdirectory `yourpackage`, so `find_packages()` can only find `scripts` as the top-level module. The entry point in this situation must be `yourscript=scripts.yourscript:cli`. Or there must be a different, deeper directory structure with `yourpackage/` subdirectory at the `setup.py` level.

Comment: Nope. Same result: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yourpackage'`; I uninstalled (`$ pip uninstall yourpackage`), then I removed the egg (`$ rm -Rf yourpackage.egg-info`) dir. And finally reinstalled (`$ pip install -e .`) Then I repeated the steps installing with (`$pip install -e yourpackage`). Same result.

Comment: BTW, this is not the first time I recreated the example, but I apologize for my sloppyness for mistaking `yourscript` for `yourpackage` in the directory name in this zillionth-iteration. It's easy to make the mistake since all of the pip output matches the name given in `setup.py`. Given the simplicity of the example, everything has a silly similar name. (>_<)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the directory structure that works:

```
yourpackage <- Any top-level directory will do
|-- setup.py
|-- yourpackage
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- scripts
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- yourscript.py
```

After `pip install -e .`:

```
`-- yourpackage.egg-info
    |-- dependency_links.txt
    |-- entry_points.txt
    |-- PKG-INFO
    |-- requires.txt
    |-- SOURCES.txt
    `-- top_level.txt
```

The entry point script works:

```
$ yourscript
Hello World!
```

Comment: `setup.py` must be at the same level as the package! Wow. I never noticed the site's example didn't include the `setup.py` file. Cheers.